# Using MembershipProvider with Windsor Castle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, castle-windsor, membership-provider

I am implementing the Windsor Container MembershipProvider with a a class. I can resolve the implementation, but it does not call the Initialize method which pulls in the values from web.config.  How can I instantiate that and make sure it calles the Initialize method?

Code to Add To Container

```
container.Register(Component.For<FNHMembershipProvider>()
    .LifeStyle.Transient
    .Named("myMembershipProvider"));

container.Register(Component.For<FNHRoleProvider>()
    .LifeStyle.Transient
    .Named("myRoleProvider"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A key point here is that you are not injecting the Membership class, you're injection the Membership PROVIDER.  The Membership class is what instatiates the membership provider based on your registry entries, and calls intialize.  The Membership class is a static class, and you can't inject it (although you could inject a wrapper class that returns the static Membership class, but I don't see a lot of benefit there).

In general, I find it to be way more pain than its worth to try to make membership use DI.

Comment: I have to use DI though based on my requirements.  So would I create the wrapper, inject it into my controller and then call that wrapper to GetUser, create user, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go. I guess that's the approach you find into the app skeleton shipped with VS template for mvc3 application. Template does not use DI, but it very easy to figure out how to switch to DI.